# How can we integrate a Flask Python web tool with the SAS platform on Azure?

Tags: python, azure, sas

On the SAS platform provided by Azure, how can we integrate the Flask Python code with our SAS platform?
The code I am trying on sas is

```
    filename url url "http://127.0.0.1:5000";
data _null_;
    infile url;
    input;
    put _infile_;
run;
```

But I dont see anything on the result window.

Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide more information. Is this on Viya? Are you running a Viya Job? Are you trying to run this in Visual Analytics? What is your application, exactly? What are you trying to do that combines SAS and Flask? You cannot just write the contents of output from Flask to a log and have it work. If you're just trying to display it in SAS then you should probably do it in Visual Analytics or through a Viya Job. SAS and Flask can talk to each other.